# ng-repeat: One-item-only source

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
$http.get("http://angularjs.uum.my/tt.json")
.success(function(response) {$scope.scrollItems = response;});

$http.get("http://angularjs.uum.my/tt2.json")
.success(function(response) {$scope.scrollItems2 = response;});
```

**tt.json - have only 1 element**

1. http://angularjs.uum.my/app/#/timetable

**tt2.json - have two 2 elements**

2. http://angularjs.uum.my/app/#/timetable2

The problem is with page no. 1, where only one element exist, the page rendered empty list repeating x number of times (where x equal to number of child elements)

Is this known bug?
How to solve this problem if the number of elements is unknown beforehand to the developer?

Please help, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a bug, your first json is

```
{"namakursus":"John", "pensyarah":"Doe", "yeh":"yeh"}
```

and the second one is

```
[
    {"namakursus":"John", "pensyarah":"Doe", "yeh":"yeh"},
    {"namakursus":"John2", "pensyarah":"Doe2", "yeh":"yeh2"}
]
```

this means the first one is not an array, so it is reapiting an object

if you want to get the same behavior your json should be and array with only 1 element, not an single object

```
[{"namakursus":"John", "pensyarah":"Doe", "yeh":"yeh"}]
```

Comment: thanks. i should be more frank with my question. I accept your answer, but please see this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090336/ng-repeat-one-item-only-source-xml